# If $\,x>1$, then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left\lfloor x^{n+1} \right\rfloor}{\left\lfloor x^n \right\rfloor}=x$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How can I prove that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left\lfloor x^{n+1} \right\rfloor}{\left\lfloor x^n \right\rfloor}=x,
$$
whenever $x>1$. Here $\left\lfloor \cdot\right\rfloor$ denotes the floor function,
or the integer part function.

The integer part $\lfloor z\rfloor$ of $z$ is the largest integer, which does not exceed $z$.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: $\frac{\left\lfloor x^{n+1} \right\rfloor}{\left\lfloor x^n \right\rfloor}$ is nearly $\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^n}$.

Comment: (-1) "This question does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since $y-1< \lfloor y\rfloor\le y$, for every $y\in\mathbb R$, then
$$
\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x^{n}}<\frac{\lfloor x^{n+1}\rfloor}{\lfloor x^n\rfloor}< \frac{x^{n+1}}{x^n-1},
$$
and hence
$$
x-\frac{1}{x^n}<\frac{\lfloor x^{n+1}\rfloor}{\lfloor x^n\rfloor}<x+\frac{x}{x^n-1},
$$
or
$$
-\frac{1}{x^n}<\frac{\lfloor x^{n+1}\rfloor}{\lfloor x^n\rfloor}-x<\frac{x}{x^n-1}.
$$
Since both
$
-\frac{1}{x^n},\,\frac{x}{x^n-1}\to 0, \quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty,
$
then $\frac{\lfloor x^{n+1}\rfloor}{\lfloor x^n\rfloor}\to x$.

Comment: Ok! Thank you Yiorgos!

Answer (score 18):

**Hint**
we have
$$y-1\le\left\lfloor y \right\rfloor\le y$$
then use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Doesn't a function need to be continuous to use that? Or is x <= y <= z enough?

Comment: This inequality is a propriety of the floor function.@AlexanderCogneau

Comment: Looks like a "nice answer" to me! ;-)